# Wrap method vs chain method

Tags: scala

Imagine we have the following:

```
sealed trait Foo
case class FullFoo[A](foo: A) extends Foo
case object EmptyFoo extends Foo
```

and

```
def liftToFoo[A](opt: Option[A]): Foo = 
  opt.map(a => FullFoo(a)).getOrElse(EmptyFoo)
```

We can easily do:

```
liftToFoo(Some(123)) // FullFoo(123)
liftToFoo(None)      // EmptyFoo
```

But I'm curious if there's some "chainable" way to call this (rather than wrapping the method like above):

```
Some(123).someFunction(liftToFoo)  // FullFoo(123)
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using an implicit class to achieve this style. Curious if there's something I can use already.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly what you're looking for but perhaps a little closer than what you've got.

```
Some(123).fold(EmptyFoo:Foo)(FullFoo(_))
```

Comment: A) Yeah, but you said you were "trying to avoid an implicit class". B) `Success()`? `Failure()`? That's a `Try`, not a `Foo`.

Comment: Re: implicits, yeah totally! Lol I hacked together this "Foo" example, but was really thinking of applying it with a Try :P You caught me in some Frankenstein copy/paste :)

Comment: Thanks again for your feedback and help!